# Failed to run custom build command for `neon-sys

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

im trying to run the firefly the app for IOTA wallet and when I do yarn in firefly-develop\packages\backend\bindings\node U get this error:

```
    error: failed to run custom build command for `neon-sys v0.5.3`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:\firefly-develop\packages\backend\bindings\node\native\target\release\build\neon-sys-7520d4ebecff611a\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  'Skipping node-gyp installation as part of npm install.'
  cargo:node_root_dir=C:\\Users\\lemon\\.electron-gyp\\9.4.4
  cargo:node_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\lemon\\\\.electron-gyp\\\\9.4.4\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib
  cargo:node_arch=x64
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  AR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  AR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_AR = None
  AR = None
  running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\lib.exe" "-out:D:\\firefly-develop\\packages\\backend\\bindings\\node\\native\\target\\release\\build\\neon-sys-1c82f1d04dd3c65f\\out\\libneon.a" "-nologo" "D:\\firefly-develop\\packages\\backend\\bindings\\node\\native\\target\\release\\build\\neon-sys-1c82f1d04dd3c65f\\out\\native\\build\\Release\\obj\\neon\\neon.obj"
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\firefly-develop\packages\backend\bindings\node\native\target\release\build\neon-sys-1c82f1d04dd3c65f\out\native\build\Release\obj\neon\neon.obj'
  exit code: 1181

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\lib.exe" "-out:D:\\firefly-develop\\packages\\backend\\bindings\\node\\native\\target\\release\\build\\neon-sys-1c82f1d04dd3c65f\\out\\libneon.a" "-nologo" "D:\\firefly-develop\\packages\\backend\\bindings\\node\\native\\target\\release\\build\\neon-sys-1c82f1d04dd3c65f\\out\\native\\build\\Release\\obj\\neon\\neon.obj" with args "lib.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1181).
```

Comment: please provide [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You are running Visual Studio 2019 tools. You need to install the Visual Studio 2017 tools, fire up the (I'm assuming you are building x64) "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt For VS 2017" and build everything in THAT command box.

Just go download the VS 2017 tools directly from Microsoft, then use the command boxes it installs to run your builds. DO NOT install them via "npm install -g windows-build-tools" as that is yet another headache of old compatibility problems, especially when you have VS 2019 already installed. The builds that neon sets up on the fly specifically require the old runtime and these old build tools. Your application? Ya, you will need to build that in these command boxes also.

If you are feeling especially bored, the real solution is to set up all your environment variables and paths to specifically pick the VS2017 tools instead of the VS2019 ones in whatever shell you are using. They used to supply 'vcvars.bat' or some such that would do this. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.